# Recyclerview with PIcasso repeating images

Tags: android-studio

My recyclerview is repeating images instead of  rendering new ones when it recycles .  The textviews are updating so this is  only the  images that have this issue . I have used Log.d  to check the URLs  and these are correct but never rendered . I have done some research and implemented suggested solutions to no avail .

```
category_list_item category_list_item = category_list_items.get(position);
        if(category_list_item.getImage_url()!=null ) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(category_list_item.getImage_url()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).resize(120, 60).into(imageView);
            holder.draft_title.setText(category_list_item.getTitle());
            holder.draft_price.setText(category_list_item.getPrice());
            holder.city_name.setText(category_list_item.getCity_name());
        }else {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
```

Comment: I set setIsRecyclable(false)in ViewHolder constructor  which resolves the issue but slows the  scrolling down .

Comment: Is this code inside the ViewHolder creation or in the BindViewHolder?

Comment: This is  in the Bind View Holder .

Comment: Well, for some reason your images are being cached as part of the ViewHolder recycle cache. Did you have getItemCount() method implemented? Can you post all your adapter code? It is very dificult to help without seeing the entire adapter. Other thing: If there is no more solution than using `setIsRecyclable(false)` don't avoid Picassos's own cache because it can help to make scrolling smoother. Downloading every image again if it returns to screen viewport is a bad thing.

Comment: I found the problem .   ` into(imageView)`  should read `into(holder.imageView)`  . The image view was not bound to the  viewholder .

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue with repeating same images working with multiple list with one adapter. I tried so many methods even i tried both glide and Picasso finally I found the solution to this problem is

setIsRecyclable(flase) method in side a View Holder method[image]